# failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found - works fine in iOS simulator but not on iphone

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

This code works fine in the iOS simulator and it displays the PDF file, however I get this error when I run the same code on my iPhone "failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found"

```
NSString *urlAdress= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://foodinspections.ocgov.com/foodinspections/inspectionArchives/%@.pdf",
                      self.inspectionResult.serialNumber];

NSLog(@"url= %@", urlAdress);

NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress]];


[self.webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Print the contents of `pdfData`. Does it begin with `%PDF`?

Comment: I'm confused now.  I did NSLog(@"pdfData= %@", pdfData); and shows a lot of data when I run it on the simulator.  However, it shows (null) when I run it from the iPhone.

Comment: This is part of the data from the simulator - pdfData= <25504446 2d312e32 200a25e2 e3cfd320 0a312030 206f626a 200a3c3c 200a2f54 79706520 2f436174 616c6f67 200a2f50 61676573 20322030 2052200a 2f506167 654d6f64 65202f55 73654e6f 6e65200a 2f566965 77657250 72656665 72656e63 6573203c 3c200a2f 46697457 696e646f 77207472 7565200a 2f506167 654c6179 6f757420 2f53696e 676c6550 61676520 0a2f4e6f 6e46756c 6c536372 65656e50 6167654d 6f646520 2f557365 4e6f6e65 200a3e3e 200a3e3e 200a656e 646f626a

Comment: Yes, that starts with "%PDF" (0x25504446).

Comment: And being nil means your app can't fetch the data. Try getting it with an NSURLRequest and see what the error is.

Comment: I put this code NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSLog(@"requestObj= %@", requestObj);  and then I get this in the console requestObj= <NSURLRequest: 0x17d4b890> { URL: http://foodinspections.ocgov.com/foodinspections/inspectionArchives/DA9812946.pdf }

Comment: @user2974739 Did you find a solution, please let us know. Even I am facing the same problem. requestObj= <NSURLRequest: 0x15e14cb0> { URL: file:///file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E297ADF1-32AC-43B0-8BAB-979C2F0E5108/Documents/FCELB/templates/aaf1040%20-%20Copy.pdf },  pdf data is (null)